# Passing result of multiple observables into object

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Given an observables with data like underneath:

```
[
{
  userId: 12,
  anotherUserId: 23,
  aField: 'test',
  anotherField: 'test2'
}
]
```

How can I use RXJS to get the result of the two userIds through

```
this.userService.getUser(id)
```

and pass that result into the object?

```
this.someService.getObjects()
    .pipe(
      ????
    )
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
```

So what I need as result after subscription should be like:

```
[
{
  userId: { 
    firstName: 'user 1', 
    lastName: 'name 1',
  }
  anotherUserId: { 
    firstName: 'user 23', 
    lastName: 'name 23',
  }
  aField: 'test',
  anotherField: 'test2'
}
, ...
]
```

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Answer (score 0):

To catch result of multiples observables you can use `forkJoin`

```
forkJoin(
  {
    foo: this.someService.getObjects(),
    foo1: this.someService.getObjects(),
    users: ajax.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users')
  }
).subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

For a better use, I recommend read the [docs](http://learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html).